# React Google sign in side webview respond like one moment please keep stuck with loading

Tags: reactjs, webview, google-signin

React app project embedded inside react native with web view

Google sign doesn't give response

have you know tip to fix that ?

Comment: Yea I been facing the error as well but it seems there isn't a solution to it yet beside this post I read : https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/issues/116

Comment: I skip that way , react native social authentication has implemented by native sdk on a WebViewGB, I am just transferring message to react native and web view